# Prove that exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $S\cap C\cap B((0,0,0),\epsilon)=\{(0,0,0)\}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I can't find the way to do this exercise.

> We consider $S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}: f(x,y,z)=0 \}$, where $f$ is a $C^1$function on $\mathbb{R^3}$ such that $f(0,0,0)=0$ and $\nabla f(0,0,0)=(0,0,1)$.
>
> Let $C=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}: z\geq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \}$. Prove that exists $\epsilon >0$ such that
>
> \begin{equation}
> S\cap C\cap B((0,0,0),\epsilon)=\{(0,0,0)\}.
> \end{equation}

I first thought about the implicit function theorem, but I don't know. Any hint is appreciated.

Thank you.